# Call stage from function in Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have in my Jenkinsfile:

```
def foo = ["1", "2", "3"]

def parallelStagesFromMap = foo.collectEntries {
    ["Build ${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(bar) {
    return {
        stage("Build ${bar}") {
            echo "Building for ${bar}"
        }
    }
}
```

I can then use them with parallel `parallel parallelStagesFromMap` but now I'm trying to call one in particular, for example:

`generateStage("a")` and it is just skipped... Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are missing closure invocation. Your `generateStage(name)` method returns a closure, and this closure is not invoked implicitly. *(It works with parallel stages, because `parallel` method expects a map where each entry value is a closure, so it iterates over all map entries and invokes collected closures).*

Here is what your example should look like to add a non-parallel stage to the pipeline using `generateStage(name)` method:

```
def foo = ["1", "2", "3"]

def parallelStagesFromMap = foo.collectEntries {
    ["Build ${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(bar) {
    return {
        stage("Build ${bar}") {
            echo "Building for ${bar}"
        }
    }
}

node {
    parallel parallelStagesFromMap

    generateStage("skipped") // no invocation, stage is skipped

    generateStage("nonparallel").call()
}
```

And here is what the Blue Ocean UI looks like after running this exemplary pipeline:

[image]