# How do I add Dynamic stages based on files in a folder in my SCM system?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I looked at [Call stage from function in Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340071/call-stage-from-function-in-jenkinsfile) which did some of what I wanted, but I had issues adding the code from the answer to my pipeline. I want to be able to scan for files in a folder and generate a stage for each file:

```groovy
def foo = sh (
    script: 'find ./collections/*.json  -printf "%f\n"',
    returnStdout: true
).trim().split("\n")

def parallelStagesFromMap = foo.collectEntries {
    ["Build ${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(bar) {
    return {
        stage("Build ${bar}") {
            echo "Building for ${bar}"
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent { label 'myExecutor' }

    triggers {
        pollSCM('') // empty cron expression string
        cron('H 6 * * 1-5')    // run every weekday at 06:00 https://crontab.guru/#0_6_*_*_1-5
    }
    options {
        timeout(time: 20, unit: "MINUTES")
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10', artifactNumToKeepStr: '10'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            steps {
                script {
                    foo = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
                }
            }
        }
        stage('parallel') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesFromMap
                    generateStage("skipped") // no invocation, stage is skipped
                    generateStage("nonparallel").call()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo ' * * *  Doing POST actions'
            //...
        }
    }
}

node {
    parallel parallelStagesFromMap

    generateStage("skipped") // no invocation, stage is skipped

    generateStage("nonparallel").call()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a hybrid between declarative and scripted pipelines, but it can be done like this:

Essentially you need to define the variables and execute the lookup in the setup stage and then run the stage generating code in a subsequent stage.

The `node` block is executed after the pipeline as you have put it, and the variable definitions are called before the code is checked out.

```groovy
def foo

def parallelStagesFromMap

def generateStage(bar) {
    return {
        stage("Build ${bar}") {
            echo "Building based on file ${bar}"
        }
    }
}


pipeline {
    agent { label 'myExecutor' }

    triggers {
        pollSCM('') // empty cron expression string
        cron('H 6 * * 1-5')    // run every weekday at 06:00 https://crontab.guru/#0_6_*_*_1-5
    }
    options {
        timeout(time: 20, unit: "MINUTES")
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10', artifactNumToKeepStr: '10'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            steps {

                script {

                    //scan collections folder for .json files
                    foo = sh (
                        script: 'find ./collections/*.json  -printf "%f\n"',
                        returnStdout: true
                    ).trim().split("\n")

                    parallelStagesFromMap = foo.collectEntries {
                       ["Build ${it}" : generateStage(it)]
                    }

                }
                //  do other setup-y stuff...
            }
        }
        stage('Parallel Dynamic') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340071/call-stage-from-function-in-jenkinsfile
                    parallel parallelStagesFromMap
                    //generateStage("skipped") // no invocation, stage is skipped
                    //generateStage("nonparallel").call()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('static stage') {
            steps {
                // step to the mic ...
            }
        }
        // more stages ...
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo ' * * *  Doing POST actions'
            //...
        }
    }
}
```